# Delphi - change input numbers layout in TEdit

Tags: delphi, input, layout, keyboard, arabic

I have a registration form made by Delphi in which user writes their phone number in a TEdit field and the form BiDiMode is bdRightToLeft since its an Arabic App.

I need to keep the BiDiMode as it is, but the numbers appear in Arabic format 
and I need them to appear in English format.

I tried:

```
var
  lang: HKL;
begin
  {
    where pcKeyboard is:
    '00000401' - arabic
    '00000409' - english
    '00000419' - russian
    '00000422' - ukrainian
    '00000407' - german
    '0000040C' - french
    '00000410' - italian
    '00000416' - portuguese
    '0000040A' - spanish
  }
  lang := LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409', 0);
  ActivateKeyboardLayout(lang, KLF_ACTIVATE);
```

But it only changes the keyboard to the language in the 'Lang' parameter and still the numbers are shown in Arabic format despite the face that the keyboard layout has actually changed.

How can I make TEdit or any kind of field show only English numbers format in an Arabic Interface?

Comment: What do your mean by "Arabic format"? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Comment section doesn't allow for Arabic numbers, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the layout, I think your problem is with Unicode and Non-Unicode characters.
Open the CharMap app and you could find everything you need.
Find differences between the Unicode code or the Ascii code of those two, maybe you have to make a small converter.
If you are using Delphi 2009 or higher versions you can use below functions.
for converting Arabic to English (Unicode digits to Non-Unicode digits) you can use something like this:

```
function ArabicDigitsToEnglish(AText: string): string;
const
  EnglishDigits = '0123456789';
  ArabicDigits = '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹';
var
  I: Integer;
  TempString: string;
begin
  TempString := AText;
  for I := 1 to Length(EnglishDigits) do
    TempString := StringReplace(TempString, ArabicDigits[i], EnglishDigits[i],
      [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := TempString;
end;
```

And for converting English digits to Arabic digits you can use something like this:

```
function EnglishDigitsToArabic(AText: string): string;
const
  EnglishDigits = '0123456789';
  ArabicDigits = '۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹';
var
  I: Integer;
  TempString: string;
begin
  TempString := AText;
  for I := 1 to Length(EnglishDigits) do
    TempString := StringReplace(TempString, EnglishDigits[i], ArabicDigits[i],
      [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result := TempString;
end;
```

Comment: It worked so perfectly as intended. Thanks a lot ^^